# Apache2 - Using a lowercase subdomain to serve an uppercase folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Currently the website being hosted uses the following structure of test.mysite.com/{site} which then serves /var/www/test/{site}

I've been trying to create a virtualhost that can match several subdomains and serve the folders under /var/www/test/. The urls would look like {site}.test.mysite.com

I've tried several approaches, one using virtual document root:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.test.mysite.com

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/test/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well except that the folders under /var/www/test/ are in uppercase and I cant seem to get the %1 to uppercase.

A different approach was using mod rewrite as specified on the apache site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.test.mysite.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap upper int:toupper
    RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

    RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^[a-z0-9-]+\.test\.mysite\.com$           
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\.test\.mysite\.com/$ /var/www/test/${upper:$1}/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

However it never seems to actually rewrite and just keeps serving the default apache document root.

I'd prefer not to have to change the name of all the folders to lowercase due to other dependencies. Are there any other options for doing this?

Comment: Configure apache to ignore case sensitivity?

Comment: Have you tried symlinks?

Comment: Creating symlinks does solve the problem when using VirtualDocumentRoot however this is not a long term solution as the underlying folder structure changes regularly. Having to manually add/remove symlinks all the time is not very practical.

Comment: having the exact same problem. tried "CheckCaseOnly On" "/var/www/test/${upper:$1}" nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is wrong: RewriteRule, here, only apply to the full path of the URL which does not include the host. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.test\.mysite\.com$           
RewriteRule .* /var/www/test/${upper:%1}$0 [L]
```

Comment: This is correct, but op needs to set the document root, this will cause a redirect like `foo.test.mysite.com/var/www/test/FOO` which I don't think is the intended result

Comment: I've tried however this creates a redirect to something.test.mysite.com/index.html/index.html/index.html etc.